# How to tackle getElementById vs a loop in php

Tags: php, javascript

please guide me in right direction if you can.

**My Situation**

I have a script that pulls data in a `PHP` for loop. In that loop there is a parameter called `Price`.In the same loop im using a javascript function to convert the `Price`, from `Jap Yen` to `Aus Dollars` and finally display the price in `Aus Dollars`.

**Problem**

Im using `getElementById` to show the Price in AUD and here's my js funciton

```
function CarCostCalculatorSINGLE(enteredPriceInYen,spanID){

    document.getElementById("calPriceInAudSINGLE"+spanID).innerHTML="$"+TotalCarCostInAUD.formatMoney(0, '.', ',');
}
```

And in my php script, Im using a counter to add a number to the end of the span so the `IDs` don't clash.

```
$callPriceInAudCounter++; 
<span id="calPriceInAudSINGLE<?php echo $callPriceInAudCounter; ?>">AUD Price Goes Here</span> 

<script>
    CarCostCalculator(<?php echo $fields['price']; ?>, <?php echo $callPriceInAudCounter; ?>);
</script>
```

**Im Lost**

Im now lost becuase on some pages I have to `include` loops to show `Side bar content` etc and the `IDs` clash bigtime. This is not the best way to tackle this and I have no idea what else I can do to stay in the loop and show the price without duplicating the functions . Is there an alternative to `getElementById` or can you guys please guide me what's the best way to tackle this?

Please tell me if you want me to clarify more, Im more than happy to.

Comment: I think you'll have to show us the generated HTML (not the PHP) for the page that you're trying to solve an issue for.  Too hard to follow what you're asking without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Why not just calculate the price in PHP rather than in javascript?

Comment: @Supericy because there are more things happening in that function to calculte the final price. Its not just converting. Becuase of that I `have` to use the function, isnt it? Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: plz show how do you `include` in `loop`

Comment: @user1889007 Ok fair enough. Just out of curiosity, is there a typo in your `CarCostCalculatorSINGLE` function? You don't use `enteredPriceInYen` for anything.

Comment: @ahoo This is a wordpress site, so my main product page is built with few different `widgets` if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Supericy SOrry. This is something i made up quickly, but my live code doesnt have that typo.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried to do a jsFidde to show you guys, but its quite hard as this happends in a Wordpress site with help of few widgets etc

Comment: @user1889007 plz give us `view source` in your browser at your page to see your generated HTML code

Comment: Well, I don't think your question is clear enough as it stands to likely get a particular good answer.  You will need to do something to make the problem statement clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but you could use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

```
<?php $elementID = uniqid('calPriceInAudSINGLE'); ?>

<span id="<?php echo $elementID ?>">AUD Price Goes Here</span> 

<script>
    CarCostCalculator(<?php echo $fields['price']; ?>, "<?php echo $elementID ?>");
</script>
```

If you have jQuery available, then I can give you a better solution.

```
<span class="aud-price" data-yen-price="<?php echo $fields['price']; ?>">AUD Price Goes Here</span>
```

And then somewhere in your javascript:

```
// onload (assuming all the elements are loading at once (ie not AJAX))
$(function () {
    $(".aud-price").each(function () {
        var self = $(this);

        self.html( "$"+TotalCarCostInAUD.formatMoney(self.data("yen-price"), '.', ',') );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have jQuery available would you mind proving the better solution?